# What's wrong with this (compiler bug)?

Tags: scala, type-inference, existential-type

I am sorry for such non-descriptive title, but I really don't know how to express this better.

```
class Foo[T]
Seq(new Foo[String], new Foo[Int]).groupBy(_ => 1).map { case (k, Seq(v)) => k -> v }.toMap
<console>:12: error: Cannot prove that (Int, Foo[_146]) forSome { type _146 >: Int with String } <:< (T, U).
```

WTF? 
If I use `.mapValues` instead of `.map`, it works. Also, making `Foo` covariant fixes it too, but in that case I end up with `Map[Int,Foo[Any]]`
What's going on here? Any ideas?

Comment: What type do you *want* to end up with?

Comment: `Map[Int, Foo[_]]` would be good

Answer (score 4):

Without variance, you create a somewhat "nonsensical" sequence:

```
class Foo[T]
val in = Seq(new Foo[String], new Foo[Int]) // Seq[_ >: Int with String]]
```

There is simply no common LUB between `Foo[String]` and `Foo[Int]`. You may assign it an existential type:

```
val in = Seq[Foo[_]](new Foo[String], new Foo[Int])
```

Then we can try to continue:

```
val in = Seq[Foo[_]](new Foo[String], new Foo[Int])
val g  = in.groupBy(_ => 1)  // Map[Int, Seq[Foo[_]]]
// the next line would produce a match error, thus make it a `def`
def m  = g.map { case (k, Seq(v)) => k -> v } // Iterable[(Int, Foo[_])]
def p  = m.toMap  // cannot prove that (Int, Foo[_]) <:< (T, U)
```

Again the existential type bites you here in disallowing a useful inference for the value type. You can enforce it again:

```
def p  = m.toMap[Int, Foo[_]] // Map[Int,Foo[_]]
```

AFAIK, Scalac will not infer existential types for you.

---

If you are thinking you have `Foo[Any]` here, you need to add a variance annotation:

```
class Foo[+T]
val in = Seq(new Foo[String], new Foo[Int]) // Seq[Foo[Any]]
def m = in.groupBy(_=>1).map {case (k,Seq(v)) => k->v}.toMap // Map[Int,Foo[Any]]
```

Comment: I don't want `Foo[Any]`, I want an existential type. `.toMap[Int, Foo[_]]` works, thank you ... that's about the only option I have not tried :) I still don't understand why `.map` and `.mapValues` work differently (the latter does work, and I don't even need `.toMap`- which is redundant, because the result of `.map` and `.mapValues` is already a map). 
Also,  why does `.grouBy` work in the first place? If the type the values if known after `groupBy`, then mapping the values to head of seq should not make it any worse, should it?